# What is the proper cooking time for steaming whole stone crabs? Is there any reason to avoid them?

Tags: cooking-time, seafood, steaming, crab

In several pages of Google results, I found no information at all on cooking time, average market prices, recipes, etc. for whole stone crabs. I made my own estimation for cooking time last time I tried, which worked sufficiently well, but would like to hear a more authoritative answer for food safety reasons.

Additionally, what's the reason for the lack of information? I have heard the assertion that they're not very palatable offered as a reason for why they're rarely eaten, but I found them perfectly tasty, though quite different from blue crabs. There was quite a lot of meat in the body, and it seems unlikely that I'd be alone in finding them palatable. I also understand that in Florida it is illegal to land whole stone crabs, but there is no such restriction in many other areas, where they're commonly sold. Is there any reason why one should not eat whole stone crabs?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florida_stone_crab#Fishery